# Loop through list and return new integer value based on string criteria

Tags: python

I'm looking at a list in the following format;

```
lst = [ '1,000 per month', '1,200 per month', '300 per week', '1,200 per month']
```

and trying to create a loop that runs through and converts any string with 'month' to simply just its int value, but for any string that contains 'week' to convert to int and then apply a calculation of int * 52 / 12 (essentially converting a weekly value into a monthly value). So the list should look like the below;

```
new_lst = ['1000', '1200', '1300', '1200']
```

Below is my abomination of an attempt;

```
for i in lst:
if string.find('week'):
    return [re.sub("[^0-9]", "", s) for i in lst] * 52 / 12
else:
    return [re.sub("[^0-9]", "", s) for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close!

We can loop through the list and modify the list in place. For each string, we check if the word you want is in it. If it is, we keep remove everything except the numbers using regex and finally convert the string to an int:

```
import re

lst = [ '1,000 per month', '1,200 per month', '300 per week', '1,200 per month']

for count, i in enumerate(lst):
    if 'week' in i:
        lst[count] = int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", i)) * 52 // 12
    elif 'month' in i:
        lst[count] = int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", i))

print(lst) # [1000, 1200, 1300, 1200]
```

Note: If we use `/` for division, the answer comes out as a float. However if we use `//` we do integer division and the result is still an integer.

Comment: @Pie if you want a new list instead of modifying the original, you can have `new_lst = [ ]`, then change those `lst[count] = int...` to `new_lst.append(int...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Halmon already provided you a clear answer and I have upvoted his answer. You should use that as your response.

However if you are looking for a list comprehension, here's how you can go about doing it.

```
import re
lst = [ '1,000 per month', '1,200 per month', '300 per week', '1,200 per month']
lst = [re.sub("[^0-9]", "", i) if 'month' in i else str(int(int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", i))*52/12)) if 'week' in i else i for i in lst]
print (lst)
```

Output will be as per your requirement of strings:

```
['1000', '1200', '1300', '1200']
```

If the input was:

```
lst = [ '1,000 per month', '1,200 per month', '300 per week', '1,200 per year']
```

The output will be:

```
['1000', '1200', '1300', '1,200 per year']
```

retaining the year as is.

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
lst = [ '1,000 per month', '1,200 per month', '300 per week', '1,200 per month']
new_lst=[]
for i in lst:
    if i.find('week') > 0:
        new_lst.append(round(int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", i)) * 52 / 12))
    else:
        new_lst.append(int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", i)))
print(new_lst)
```

Output :

```
[1000, 1200, 1300, 1200]
```

Comment: you are assuming that if the text is not week, then its a month. Dont make that assumption. check explicitly please.

Comment: Agreed. But author of the question took that assumption himself. So, I kept it as is. Anyways.. the intention was to show him the way. :-)